# Cross Browser Debugging with Chrome remote debugging tools

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

Is it possible to debug web pages in IE,Firefox etc using chrome debugging tools..
how to deubg things in Chrome devtools using Firefox ie etc. and is there any extensions like adb (remote client) for IE, Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

> RemoteDebug is an initiative to bring a common remote debugging protocol to today's browsers.

http://remotedebug.org/

Unfortunately, IE isn't supported yet. Hovever, RemoteDebug team works closely with all browser vendors to provide support for all major browsers ( https://twitter.com/remotedebug/status/409047601733185536 ).